# Shopify Theme and ScriptTags

Tags: shopify

I'm new to Shopify app development and am a little confused with regards to the difference between ScriptTags and the Embedded App SDK.

My understanding, which might be incorrect, is that ScriptTags are best used to add functionality to the store front and that the Embedded App SDK basically allows you to integrate the administration portion of an app in the site merchant admin section. Is this correct?

Furthermore, if my app was to display an interface (i.e. a dialog with some options) to users via a ScriptTag is there anyway to integrate it into the site theme? Or would I simply add my theming, either dynamically via JS (potentially allowing merchants to edit default settings via the admin) or by loading an external CSS file via the ScriptTag (or both, I guess)?

Regardless of which approach taken, there is always the possibility that the site CSS could interfere or negatively impact the app-generated content. Is it common / best practice to reset the CSS used in a custom interface?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood your question clearly.
But I think you are referring this.
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag

1) You can't create a new page with the scripttag in Shopify.

2) You can't save any data with the scripttag within Shopify.
You can submit your customized form, but Shopify can't accept and process that form.

Because the scripttag represents javascript and the javascript is only for client side programming.

I hope this could help.